# Start New Activity on click of an item of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-activity, floating-action-button

I have a FAB on my main activity. When the user clicks on that a new activity opens and user enters details like name, address, uploads image and a few other things.I take this data and only display name and address as an item of recyclerview. So when the user clicks on the item, I want to open a new activity which displays all values. 
How do i create a new activity, every time user clicks the Fab and enter details??

Comment: Refer https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: I know this code. I cannot have predefined activity because, I do not know how many time user will make an entry. Ex. if the user presses the the FAB 25 times, i'll have to create 25 different activities?

Comment: then try with fragments

Comment: Create one activity which provides the UI to add user data. And save the user data on click of a submit button to an sqlite database (or whichever approach you prefer). start this activity whenever user presses the FAB.
Create another activity (or even you can use the same activity) and pass some unique identifier for the items selected from the RecyclerView as a bundle along with the intent while starting the activity. Fetch the details from db using the identifier and display the compelete data.

Answer (score 1):

You can write callback on RecyclerView item.
Please refer following code.

In your adapter:

```
private RecyclerViewListeners recyclerViewListeners;

 public interface RecyclerViewListeners {
        public abstract void onRecycleItemClick(List<MovieDataModel> moviesDataList, int position);
    }

    public void setCallBack(RecyclerViewListeners callBack) {
        this.recyclerViewListeners = callBack;
    }
```

in onBindViewHolder() method :

```
 holder.movieLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                recyclerViewListeners.onRecycleItemClick(movies, position);
            }
        });
```

In your java class override listener as follows and start new activity:

```
 MoviesAdapter moviesAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(movieDataModels, R.layout.movie_cell, getApplicationContext());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(moviesAdapter);
                moviesAdapter.setCallBack(new MoviesAdapter.RecyclerViewListeners() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRecycleItemClick(List<MovieDataModel> moviesDataList, int position) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MovieListActivity.this, MoviesDeatailsActivity.class);
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("Title", moviesDataList.get(position).getTitle());
                        bundle.putString("Description", moviesDataList.get(position).getOverview());
                        bundle.putInt("Id", moviesDataList.get(position).getId());
                        bundle.putDouble("Popularity", moviesDataList.get(position).getPopularity());
                        intent.putExtras(bundle);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
```

Please make changes as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the new activity by intent and by putting the data which you want to display on a new activity in that intent call

**Sending the data and Opening the new activity on fab button click event**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
String message = editText.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra("Key_Msg", message);
startActivity(intent);
```

**And you can retrieve the data in New activity coming from the previous activity like this in `onCreate` method**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra("Key_Msg");

// Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(message);
```

You can learn more about Starting Activities [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)